# floating divs that fill space until cleard divs

Tags: html, css-float

To get an idea of what the hell I'm on about, please go [Here](http://testing.jmsph.co.uk/about.php) and [Here](http://testing.jmsph.co.uk/contact.php)

As you will see there is a side bar and a content area, sidebar is floating left, content floating right, and footer clears both.

Height on the sidebar and content are not set so the divs grow!

However, you can see that if one floating div is bigger than the other, the the background image appears.

I need to know how to make the background colour of both divs always be the same, and grow together in peace and harmony

Thanks

Comment: If it helps, what you're looking for is often described as "equal-height columns" (in [this article](http://buildinternet.com/2009/07/four-methods-to-create-equal-height-columns/), for example. There will be plenty of others, and many [existing questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=equal+height+columns) here on SO.)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is for the two divs to be the same height even though their content height is different. This cannot be done without relying on tables or javascript.

What you can do to achieve the same effect, is have a container div (I can see you already have it) and give this a vertically repeating background image of the sidebar and content color. This is known as Faux Columns.

Make sure to clear within the container (move `<div class="clear"></div>` up one level) so the container gets the height of whichever div is bigger.

Comment: You can fake it with faux columns, and even use `display` in css.

Comment: I could be crazy, but I think 'faux columns' is what I'm talking about. And you can use `display` but it's very bad / doesn't have good cross-browser support.

Comment: `display` has very good browser support, only low IEs (`<7`) don't support it. Also, edit your answer slightly so I can remove the downvote, I didn't read your question properly.

Comment: Will do, and I think IE7 doesn't support it either (maybe you meant that) which still is a browser you will have to support on most websites.

Answer (score 1):

`display: table-cell` on both divs (and removing the floats) can work easily here, though lower IEs won't like it.

Or, you could always use the infamous **[Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)**